# React.js - on form submit, post data to backend and redirect page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on my first React project.

I'd like to do 2 things when a form is submitted:

1. post form data to the backend
2. redirect to a thank-you page

I am able to post the form data to the backend with handleSubmit (code below), but looking for a way to incorporate redirect.

```
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            await fetch('http://localhost:5000/results', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    return response.json();
                });
            }
        catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

This is how the handleSubmit is call on the form

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
             action="http://localhost:5000/results" method="post"
             >
```

This is what I'd like to incorporate as part of handleSubmit

```
<Redirect  to="/thank-you/" />
```

**Edit: withRouter/this.props.history.push**

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class Form extends React.Component {


handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            await fetch('http://localhost:5000/results', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    return response.json();
                    this.props.history.push("/thankyou");
                });
            }
        catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}


export default withRouter(Form);
```

**Edit 2: rewrite handleSubmit, add BrowserRouter to App**

```
//form.component.jsx

class Form extends React.Component {
  
   handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/results', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
                }).then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((json) => {
                      console.log(json)
                     this.props.history.push("/thank-you");
                })
            
        .catch((error) =>  console.log(error.message));
    };

export default Form;



//app.js

import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
 return (
  
        <BrowserRouter>

          <Route exact path='/form' component= {Form}/>
          <Route exact path='/thank-you' component={ThankYou}/>

        </BrowserRouter>
);
}
export default App;
```

Comment: In your `.then()`, set a state variable, like `this.setState( { redirect: true } )` (use an arrow function for the callback so you don't lose the proper `this`). Now you can simply add `{ this.state.redirect && <Redirect  to="/thank-you/" />}` to your component. (also note that you can use `event.target.getAttribute('action')` to grab the url from the form, or instead remove the `action` attribute from the `<form>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Redirect` component to programmatically redirect the user. `Redirect` component should be rendered in the JSX in order for it to take effect and redirect the app.

If you are using functional component, than you can use `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom` to redirect the user after form submission.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent() {
   ...
   const routerHistory = useHistory();  

   const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            ...
            routerHistory.push('/new-route');
        }
        catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

   ...
}
```

In case of class component, you can use `history` prop that is passed from the react router to the direct child components.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   ...

   handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            ...
            this.props.history.push('/new-route');
        }
        catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

   ...
}
```

If `history` prop is not defined in your class component, then you can use `withRouter` higher-order component to ensure that router props are passed to your component.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   ...
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

---

**Side note:** Inside `handleSubmit()` method, you have mixed `async-await` syntax with `promise-chaining`. Use either one of them but not both at the same time. I suggest that you use `async-await` syntax.

Using just `async-await` syntax, `handleSubmit()` method could be written like as shown below:

```
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const requestData = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
      };

      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/results', requestData);
      const data = await response.json();

      // do something with the data returned from the server as 
      // a result of POSt request
      ...
      
      // redirect
      this.props.history.push('/thank-you');
    
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
     }
}
```

Comment: hi - I tried adding `this.props.history.push('/thank-you');` before `return response.json();` and after `return response.json()`; both do not seem to be redirect to the thank-you page. Am I missing something? (I tried with the withRouter too)

Comment: Check if the browser url changes or not. If it doesn't changes, then please edit your question to show the code how it looks like when you made the changed mentioned in the answer

Comment: The browser url does not change, it stays on the form page. Backend part still works. I went ahead and edited the post with withRouter, and this.props.history.push

Comment: Any code after the `return` statement is unreachable code. Looking at your code, it seems like you don't need to use the `response` at all. If you do, then make sure you save it in the state and then redirect the app. Also, as i mentioned at the end of my answer, don't mix promise-chaining with `async-await` syntax, use either one of them, not both.

Comment: See if [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-field-srw0g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) helps you understand how you can redirect after the POST request.

Comment: Also see the code at the end of the updated answer to see how `handleSubmit` method can be written using just `async-await` syntax.

Comment: The demo you have is super helpful; however, I am still not able to get the redirect to work. I will edit one more time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221586/discussion-between-mochimuffin-and-yousaf).

Answer (score 0):

You must return `<Redirect  to="/thank-you/" />` in function render to redirect. So, i suggest you should set a modal with component `<Redirect  to="/thank-you/" />` and render it in function render.

Example:

```
 state={
        modal: null,
    }

handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
        await fetch('http://localhost:5000/results', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({modal: <Redirect  to="/thank-you/" />})
            return response.json();
        });
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

render() {
    return <div>
        ...
        {this.state.modal}
    </div>
}
```